# Is there a way to take values from column a and make it a sort of header for the data using pandas?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Currently my data looks like this:

```
| Building Name | Elevation (LAT) | Floor Classification |
| ------------- |---------------- | -------------------- |
| A             |1                | Type one             |
| A             |2                | Type one             |
| A             |3                | Type two             |
| A             |4                | Type three           |
| B             |1                | Type two             |
| B             |2                | Type two             |
| B             |3                | Type three           |
| B             |4                | Type three           |
| B             |5                | Type three           |
| C             |1                | Type one             |
| C             |2                | Type two             |
| C             |3                | Type two             |
```

I want to use pandas to take the first occurrence of unique Building names and make them sort of headers for the data in the table, so the result will look like:

```
| Building Name | Elevation (LAT) | Floor Classification |
| ------------- |---------------- | -------------------- |
| A             |                 |                      |
|               |1                | Type one             |
|               |2                | Type one             |
|               |3                | Type two             |
|               |4                | Type three           |
| B             |                 |                      |
|               |1                | Type two             |
|               |2                | Type two             |
|               |3                | Type three           |
|               |4                | Type three           |
|               |5                | Type three           |
| C             |                 |                      |
|               |1                | Type one             |
|               |2                | Type two             |
|               |3                | Type two             |
```

Does anyone know of a way to do this?

Comment: Can you express your input and output in a table format so it's easier to understand the structure of it?

Answer (score 0):

Change your columns to be a [MultiIndex](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.MultiIndex.html):

```
df = df.set_index(['Building Name', 'Elevation (LAT)'])
df
```

Result:

```
                              Floor Classification
Building Name Elevation (LAT)
A             1                           Type one
              2                           Type one
              3                           Type two
              4                         Type three
B             1                           Type two
              2                           Type two
              3                         Type three
              4                         Type three
              5                         Type three
C             1                           Type one
              2                           Type two
              3                           Type two
```

Access a given row by building and elevation (use tuples for the index):

```
df.loc[('B', 2), :]
```

gives

```
Floor Classification    Type two
Name: (B, 2), dtype: object
```

Or for a single building:

```
df.loc['C', :]
```

Result:

```
                Floor Classification
Elevation (LAT)
1                           Type one
2                           Type two
3                           Type two
```

All buildings with a single (or more) elevation(s) is a bit trickier, since you can't leave the first element of the multi-index tuple blank, or use a ':' there. Use `pandas.IndexSlice`:

```
idx = pd.IndexSlice
df.loc[idx[:, 1:2], :]
```

Result:

```
                              Floor Classification
Building Name Elevation (LAT)
A             1                           Type one
              2                           Type one
B             1                           Type two
              2                           Type two
C             1                           Type one
              2                           Type two
```

(note that `1:2` is *inclusive* the end value here. Part of the reason is that the elevations are actually *labels*, not plain numbers, and thus behave a bit differently in Pandas).